# How can I declare an empty tuple?

Tags: haskell

I can declare empty list as `[]`, but, how can I declare empty tuple?

I have tried:

```
for ( , ) 
ghci>(1,0 ) : [(,)]
```

but it gives me an error!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A tuple is a type that is always the same length and always has the same types. So `(Int, Int)` is a *different* type from `(Int, Int, Int)` and a different type from `(Int, String)`.

With this in mind, you *could* have an empty tuple. However, this would just be a type with a single value. This type is written as `()` and pronounced ***unit***. The only value of this type is also `()`.

Answer (score 4):

Note that `(,)` and friends act as *functions*.

```
ghci> (,) 2 3
(2,3)
```

Lists have two constructors: `[]` and `:`, which gives them the possibility of emptiness (`[]` representing "empty"). Tuples, however, only have one constructor each. `(,)` is the *only* constructor for the two-tuple type, meaning that tuples do not provide the possibility of emptiness. Whenever you have a two-tuple, you are guaranteed that it actually has two elements in it.